# Sending GET Request when Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to send a GET request as soon as a button is pressed. As I'm quite inexperienced with HTML and JQuery/Ajax, I'm a little bit confused as to how to do this. My code is as following

```
  <div id = "Reset">
  <!-- <form method="get"></form> -->
  <!-- <form action="https://wt.ops/reset" method="get"> -->
  <button>Reset</button>
  <!-- </form> -->
  </div>
```

```
 <script>
      $("Reset").ready(function(){
        $( "#Reset" ).click(function(){});
        $.get( "https://wt.ops/reset", function( data ) {
          $( ".result" ).html( data );
          alert( "Load was performed." );
        })});

      </script>
```

Currently what it's doing is that it just loads the JQuery scripts automatically when the page is reloaded. But when I click the button, it does nothing.

Comment: `$("Reset").ready(function()...` What is "Reset"? What are you trying to do by calling ready on Reset? Don't you wanna call ready when document is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the click handler after the document is loaded.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    //.. click handler
});
```

Your `$.get` should be within the click handler.

```
    $("#Reset").click(function(){
        $.get( "https://wt.ops/reset", function( data ) {
            $( ".result" ).html( data );
            alert( "Load was performed." );
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you have to update

**1. this is just to ask have you added the jquery script in head**

**2. You have to change the id from div to button tag or remain as it is**

```
<div>
    <!-- <form method="get"></form> -->
    <!-- <form action="https://wt.ops/reset" method="get"> -->
    <button id="Reset">Reset</button>
    <!-- </form> -->
</div>
```

**3. You have to update the script function to below function. I have only changed the url to check the data**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Reset").click(function () {
            $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("Load was performed.");
            })
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you use Jquery.

```
  <div id = "reset">
  <button  >Reset</button>
  <span id='result'> data</span>
  </div>

  $().ready(function(){
      
        $( "#reset" ).click(function(){
        console.log('click')
        getFileFromNet();
        });
        
        function getFileFromNet(){
         $.get( "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2", function( data ) {
          $( "#result" ).html( data );
          alert( "Load was performed." );
          
        })
        }
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eaLjb1n5/

Maybe it help you

Answer (score 0):

First, you add jQuery in your html file. We use ajax method for send request.

Here is my code

```
<div>
  <button id="submit">Reset</button>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on("click",function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url: "", //your url
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

if you have form data then you can submit form like this

```
<form id="form">
  <input name="name" type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").on("submit",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var f = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "", //your url
            method: "GET",
            data: f,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```